# `classname` in panel types of wagtail

Tags: wagtail

In **[Panel Types of Wagtail Page](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/panels.html#panel-types)**,

```
class wagtail.admin.edit_handlers.xxxxxPanel(field_name, classname=None, widget=None, heading='', disable_comments=False)
```

Q1: I am wondering what are the comprehensive list of possible values of **`classname=`**? Id did not find any solid reference for this argument.

Q2: And What are the purpose for introducing `classname=` ? only for rendering the Wagtail CMS editing page or it also influences the rendering of **published** HTML page? (for example, `classname=title` will render as `<h2>` tag instead of `<p>` tag in published HTML page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classname` option adds the given string to the `class="..."` attribute on the panel's HTML within the editing interface. It does not affect the front-end rendering.

Since it's just a string, you can set any value you like there, but of course it will only have an effect if there's a corresponding CSS rule for it. `full` and `title` are the only documented styles provided by Wagtail itself, but it's possible to add your own custom styles via the [insert_editor_css](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#insert-editor-css) hook.